# POST with id as object Django

Tags: python, django, rest, post

I want to be able to post object from model with FK (I'm using the django rest framework) but as integer not the whole object. I know it's important to define FK in the the model in which I want to build a relationship between two models but this caused me a problem when I try to add new instance I have to give the FK a whole instance instead of just numbered ID.

**models.py**

```
class Lounges(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Description = models.TextField()

class Price(models.Model):
    loungeID = models.ForeignKey(Lounges, related_name='price')
    priceType = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to create instance from Price and give it the lounge id not the object. Is there a way to get around this I tried many things but none worked. Thanks.

Comment: did you try my solution? let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why it created problems for you, but this is actually very simple: (btw, model attributes should be lowletters)

```
newlounge = Lounge(name="blabla", description="nlbalsahsd")

newprice  = newlounge.price.create(pricetype="sale", price=100)
```

thats it.

or (not a django-way) make `loungeID` a PositiveIntegerField

```
loungeID = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

and then

```
newlounge = Lounge(name="blalsad", description="aosijaosidjas")

newprice = Price(pricetype="sale", price=100)
newprice.loungeID = newlounge.id
newprice.save()
```

Comment: Thank you your solution is very straight forward, but I just don't know how to apply it in my view with a serializer because I'm using JSON data.